# Add new column to the existing table in Delta lake(Gen2 blob storage)

Tags: apache-spark-sql, delta-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

Curious to know, can we add a new column to the existing Delta Lake table stored in the Gen2 blob storage, based on the business use case, i will need to add additional 3 more columns to one of the table in delta lake.

```
ALTER TABLE doesn't worked for me.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want add columns to table storage?

Comment: You should be able to add new columns. Can you elaborate on _"ALTER TABLE doesn't worked for me. "_?

Comment: Hello @JacekLaskowski, thanks i was able to add a column with ALTER command. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Can you please answer your question for others to learn from you? If you think it's not worth it, please delete the question. Thank you!

Comment: @chaitrak Would you like to post your answer (with your findings) so you can mark this question as answered?